# Port Forwarding require adding 8080 to the URL noe

Tags: port-forwarding

I have finally got port forwarding working on my system, it's been a real challenge because my Modem and Router were both trying to do the job, I have now bridged my modem and it is all handled by my router.

I am trying to run Apache webserver from my IP.  To get it working I had to change my port forwarding to use port 8080 instead of port 80.

So in my Apache `httpd.conf` file I had to change `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080` and `ServerName localhost:80` to `ServerName localhost:8080`

As a result, I can now access my server from my external IP address as long as I add `:8080` to the end of the IP but I can no longer access it with `localhost` instead I have to use `localhost:8080`

So my question, is there anyway to make `localhost` work without the need of adding `:8080` to the end of it?  Also with my IP address, I  would like to not have to add `:8080` to the end of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But you can add 80 to another [`Listen` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) to have it listen on both, and then create a new virtual host that unconditionally redirects to port 8080 of the same host using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Thanks I will look into this, for now I added another `Listen 80` and this make my `localhost' work again so that's a big step thanks